# How can I maintain the original creation date or crtime of .txt files I create?

Tags: text-processing, text-editor, text

I take a lot of notes in plain `.txt` files that I write in the default text editor and it is very useful for me.  There is only one thing missing to make my "workflow" perfect. I would really like to know when the files were created. If I create one and in the future add something and save the date is overwritten.

I learned about the `stat` and `debugfs` command on this site... https://linuxhint.com/file-creation-time-linux/

Despite my `.txt` files being in an `ext4` partition nothing comes up in the created field under the `stat` function.

When I use the `debugfs` function the crtime is the same as all the other times in other words it is the last time I saved it not when I created it.

In the process of writing this I did think of a manual way around which would be adding a date to every single one of my notes and edits which obviously is a bit more tedious... I would like to see if there is an "automated" way to see this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if you add creation date to your file name: `file_2023-04-17-14-43.txt` instead of `file.txt`. You will be able to parse such name in scripts to automatically obtain creation date.

Comment: Simple but very effective, I have not thought of that.  I will highly consider that.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
stat -c %W *.txt
```

will show the creation time in unix timestamp on EXT4. But it will depend on the mount options if this is overwritten afaik.

You are better off switching to `xfs`, Version 5 and upwards supports `crtime` too and shows `Birth` when using `stat *.txt`